# MVC | Invite New User By Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I would like to give the admins in my web app (MVC 5) an option to invite user to my web app (maybe even with pre defined role).

Do I need to implement it on my own from scratch or there is anything out of the box (from Microsoft) ?

If I do need to implement it from scratch, anyone have a nice article or tutorial for explain the process and work flow.

PS. I'm working with Identity 2.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be simple workflow:

1. Generate a token
2. Send email containing link like: `site.com/Home/Register?token=123123&role=moderator`

When user follows this link, you must check if token is valid and create a new user with specified role.

Comment: Great way for intruders to change their permission level via url: `http://example.com/blah/blah?token=blah&role=admin`

Comment: @trailmax It's only explanation of approach. In real, you should compare token and params or just encrypt params in token